# Difference between git add -A vs git stage -A

Tags: git

I'm using git version 2.31.1 where I can also use `git stage .` which apparently is working like `git add .`. So apparently these commands are synonymous and adds changes to stanged for commit:

```
git add .
git stage .

git add --all
git stage --all

git add -A
git stage -A
```

Are `stage` and `add` interchangeable or do they perform some different actions?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

> This is a synonym for git-add[1]. Please refer to the documentation of that command.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stage

So there is no difference between `git stage` and `git add`.